# layout_width has no effect on custom info window

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to customize info windows of markers on a map. I created infowindowlayout.xml as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/placeName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vicinity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/placeName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/placeName"
        android:gravity="right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My InfoViewAdapter implementation looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    if(contentView == null)
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindowlayout, null);

    TextView placeNameView = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.placeName); // Place
    TextView vicinityView = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.vicinity); // Vicinity
    TextView distanceView = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.distance); // Distance

    Place place = markerMap.get(marker.getId());

    // Setting all values in listview
    placeNameView.setText(place.getName());
    vicinityView.setText(place.getVicinity());
    distanceView.setText(place.getDistance());

    return contentView;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, I have "wrap_content" all over the place. However, when I click on a marker, the Info Window is shown much wider than necessary. When I change layout_width of RelativeLayout in the XML, it has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: move the code of `getInfoContents()` to `getInfoWindow()`

Comment: When you use wrap_content at that time if the String is very long then it will be display according to it and if String is small then it will small window. So change width with match_parent or give it to fix width.

Comment: @johntheripp3r: it doesn't help :(

Comment: @PiyushGupta: as I said, when I set layout_width of RelativeLayout to a fixed width, it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` works best when it can know its parent container. For example, in `getView()` of an `Adapter`, it is best to use the three-parameter `inflate()` method that takes the parent `ViewGroup` as the second parameter. In your case, that's not possible, which is why you are passing in `null` as the second parameter to `inflate()`.

I would try to switch to some other root container class. Or, try wrapping the `RelativeLayout` in an otherwise-pointless `FrameLayout`, and see if that helps.

Comment: I wrapped the `RelativeLayout` in a `FrameLayout`. `layout_width="wrap_content"` still doesn't work, but I can at least give a fixed width for the Info Window.